# r-base-dev won't install due to dependencies

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu

I'm new to stackoverflow, R and Ubuntu...here goes.  I have a windows machine running a virtual Ubuntu machine with Oracle VM Virtual box.  My Ubuntu is 32 bit and was installed as part of a Coursera course on data mining.

I am trying to get word2vec.c and word2phrase.c to compile and be used in R by using the system command.  I've done a bunch of research and found that pthread.h is not supported on windows machines so I thought I would install R on the Ubuntu virtual machine to solve this problem.  I have followed the instructions to install R on Ubuntu found here: http://sites.psu.edu/theubunturblog/installing-r-in-ubuntu/  When I install the base R package with `sudo apt-get install r-base` it works fine, but when I try to install the r-base-dev applications with `sudo apt-get install r-base-dev` I get the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: cdbs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried to install build-essential, but I get a warning/error message like this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I go tried to install dpkg-dev, and it's dependencies until I reach a dead-end with this warning:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.17.5ubuntu5) but 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 is to be installed
            Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: fakeroot but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libalgorithm-merge-perl but it is not going to be installed
```

There appears to be circular logic here where it recommends build-essntial but I was trying to install libdpkg-perl so I could install build-essential...I must be missing something here   Please help!

I've read enough to know that I need the R development kit to use install.packages in R, so if I can't resolve this issue, I won't be able to install or include any standard libraries in my R scripts.

Comment: Have a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/484750/why-build-essential-failed

Comment: Your system is messed up.  That should not have happened.  I have not seen it in _countless_ installations. The suggestion by Steven Beaupré looks prescient.  Please try that, and then proceed.  If it still fails please come to the [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian) mailing list for R on Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: This answer from the link that Steven Beaupre provided did the trick.  THANK YOU!!!

"Run sudo apt-get install libdpkg-perl=1.17.5ubuntu5 to downgrade libdpkg-perl.
You somehow installed a newer version of the package than what is in the repositories, which is causing problems with other packages."  Steven add your comment as an "Answer" and I'll give it the thumbs up as the correct response. :)

Comment: This solved the immediate problem, but there turned out to be many more issues like this.  In the end I just gave up and installed a fresh/clean (non-coursera) version of Ubuntu as a virtual machine and that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end the problem was that the Ubuntu image I downloaded was corrupted. I re-downloaded it and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I followed to install R on fresh Ubuntu 15.04(Vivid) install yesterday:

1. sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu **vivid**/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
2. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install r-base
5. sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

You may need to replace **vivid** by your ubuntu

Comment: Nice answer but inapplicable as OP runs a different release.  You essentially restated the README, and yes, this generally works.